# How to Connect to GCP Services without Using JSON file in Java

Tags: google-iam, spring-cloud-gcp

I am Trying to connect to GCP PUSUB Services using IAM authentication. I want to do this without the .json file.

I tried using

```
GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(() -> httpTransport);
```

But this is too required application_default_credentials.json file to get Authenticated .

Basically , I want to get Authorized using  GCP IAM API to use GCP PUBSUB Services .

Plan - I  Want to run a sample Java code from my local , connecting to GCP PUBSUB instance and test and after testing , Deploying the same at  GCP container and then test the same PUBSUB.

to Connect to GCP PUBSUB instance from  my  local system I want to  do  that Via IAM Authentication mechanism .

Any reference ? Please help

thanks

Comment: Where are you executing your code (Google Cloud or elsewhere)? If elsewhere you will need credentials of some type. Your options are User Credentials (Google OAuth), a service account JSON file, a user impersonating a service account, or Workload Identity Federation. If you are running in Google Cloud, use the attached service account (metadata service). Edit your question with more details.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Plan is  - I  Want to run a sample Java code from my local , connecting to GCP PUBSUB instance and test and after testing , Deploying the same at  GCP container and then test the same PUBSUB. 

to Connect to GCP PUBSUB instance from  my  local system I want to  do  that Via IAM Authentication mechanism .

Comment: For development, use the Google Cloud SDK CLI (gcloud). That tool will set up credentials (gcloud auth application-default login) for your applications. See @elena-Felder's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Application default credentials can be setup with [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud). Once you install gcloud, `gcloud auth application-default login` will allow all the client libraries and Spring Cloud GCP modules to get your credentials from the environment.